# what will happen if a cluster queue is deleted without taking it out of the cluster

Tags: ibm-mq

a cluster queue part of a single cluster is deleted without taking the queue out of the cluster in IBM MQ v9.1
. What issue will it cause?

Comment: Did you try and what happened?

Answer (score 2):

Some messages might already be en-route to this queue, sitting on transmission queues, being moved by channels, and when the messages arrive at the target queue manager, the cluster channel will try to put them to the queue only to discover it has been deleted. The messages will hopefully then end up on a DLQ, but if you don't have one, and the messages are persistent, the channel will stop so that the messages stay safe, and that will mean other messages can't get through.

Altering the queue to take it out of the cluster, means that any en-route messages can still be put to the queue when they arrive, but no new messages will be sent that way as the queue is no longer in the cluster.

Then you can wait a little while - make sure all channels are running so all en-route messages can get through - and once no more messages are arriving for that queue, you can delete it later without the above problems happening.